# Ruby 3.1.0 encoding(?) problem in irb (RubyInstaller Windows 10)

Tags: irb, rubyinstaller

Since the update to 3.1.0 via RubyInstaller under Win 10 there is a problem with `alt gr` in irb. When I try to enter `{` (German keyboard `alt gr` + `{`) I get `^[{`. Any idea what's going wrong? BTW 3.0.2 was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

```
git clone https://github.com/ruby/reline

cd reline

rake install
```

https://github.com/ruby/reline/pull/425

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Eric perfect, thanks! Can't believe a default ruby environment installed on Windows with rubyinstaller using default settings is still suffering from this kind of basic issues in 2023...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can install or update reline using gem :

```
gem install reline
```

This issue (altgr+4 => ^[{) also occurs with irb/ruby installed via msys2.
As a side effect you might notice a speed up when copy/pasting inside irb.

Ps: not enough reputation to just comment previous answer